# Git: Can't locate Git/Hooks.pm

Tags: git, perl, unix

Writing a driver script for my git hooks in Perl.  Unfortunately, I keep getting this syntax error that doesn't make sense.

```
Can't locate Git/Hooks.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /path/to/myLibraries.)
```

I understand it is looking for Git/Hooks.pm in my include directories.  Unfortunately, I only see the Git directory, but no Hooks.pm file.

I tried finding `Hooks.pm` on GitHub (i.e. source code of Git), but can't even find it there.

https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/perl/Git

The only thing I see in the library I am using is `I18N.pm IndexInfo.pm SVN SVN.pm`, which is exactly what I see for git's source code.

Does this file even exist...anywhere?  If so, where and when I find it can I just copy it into the directory and call it good?

Comment: [Git::Hooks](https://metacpan.org/pod/Git::Hooks).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your program includes `use Git::Hooks;`, but that you didn't install the module. You should use your system's package manager to install it if you're using your system perl.

Comment: Where is that module located?  Online somewhere?  I'm googling and coming up with nothing.

Comment: Hopefully, in your systems package manager (`apt-get`? `yum`?). You should avoid installing modules for your system by any other means, but the risk of harm is mininal. If your package manager doesn't have it, `sudo cpan Git::Hook` should be fine. This will get it from CPAN, the repository for Perl modules.

Comment: I found the module here https://github.com/gnustavo/Git-Hooks/blob/next/lib/Git/Hooks.pm since it was from a tutorial I was following.  I can't find it on CPAN, though.

Comment: Like the first two times you asked, I'm going to recommend using your system's package manager (with `cpan` as a fallback).

Comment: @MrPickles: [Here it is on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~gnustavo/Git-Hooks-1.3.0/lib/Git/Hooks.pm)

Comment: I meant `cpan` the command line tool. The full command was posted above.